# Author byline field no longer reflected in News webpart author field

Tags: sharepoint-online

When previously creating a blog post or news post on SharePoint online, the author by-line field would always filter through to the News Part author field, over-riding the created by field. This allowed the display of news items written by one member of staff in another members name.

Indeed, our old news posts and blogs posts still show this.

New posts however are reverting to the created by author field regardless of whether the author by-line is completed or is set to a different individual.

Has anything changed recently in SharePoint Online / Office 365 that would affect this?

Comment: I reproduce your issue, per my test, newly created news post has no Author byline value in site pages library, so even if we change the author, it will always show created by author.Searched in mseeage center, and no relevant information was searched in the mseeage center, we suggest you request a ticket to Microsoft.

Comment: Yes we are experiencing the same issue. This was working a week ago.

Comment: I have direct premium support with MS and getting them to investigate in ticket 24739702

Comment: A year on and this still happens - was it ever resolved @DavidLiong ?